# Active Directory. Members are the only users to see Members

Tags: permissions, active-directory

Active directory functional level "Windows Server 2008 R2"

I would like to hide "Members" from all Authenticated Users except for the members of the group in question.

I assumed that "SELF" would help with this but it does not appear to do the trick. Here is the test setup:

OU "Tester" Group "TestGroup"

Two users one admin user and one non admin (TestUser).

I create TestGroup in the Tester OU. I add TestUser as a member of the group.

At the OU level I add "Deny, Authenticated Users, Read Members".

I test and TestUser cannot see any Members (expected).

On TestGroup I add "Allow, SELF, Read Members".

I test and TestUser cannot see any Members (not expected).

Next on TestGroup I add "Allow, TestUser, Read Members".

I test and TestUser can see the Members (expected).

My next test is on TestGroup I add "Allow, TestGroup , Read Members". Then I remove the "Allow, TestUser, Read Members" rule.

I test and TestUser cannot see the Members (expected as I assume this is the same as SELF).

It appears that in order to see the members of a group the user in question must have permission from another group (not the group in question) (or the user itself) to read members. Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

After much testing and head banging I realized the answer.  It is quite simple and makes sense.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cc7f3927-40c7-47bf-89a9-4b30a376ea77/only-members-can-see-members?Thread%3Acc7f3927-40c7-47bf-89a9-4b30a376ea77=Microsoft.Forums.Data.Models.Discussion&ThreadViewModel%3Acc7f3927-40c7-47bf-89a9-4b30a376ea77=&forum=winserverDS